# Can't Refresh a JFrame/JSsrollPane

Tags: java, jframe, jscrollpane

This code is used to get a specific data from an xml file that we entered in jtextfield, until it works well the first time like it's showed in the image, but the problem starts when we want to search for another data, I get the data (I've already tested it) but I can't refresh the value in the table
[the image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVb9r.jpg)

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.UIManager;

import javax.swing.JMenuBar;

import javax.swing.JTextField;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;

import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;


import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;


import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.JTable;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;


import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;






public class Frame1 {

private JFrame frame;

private JTextField searchField;
int i=0;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */


public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame1 window = new Frame1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * parse Data
 */
private JTable parseData(String st){
    JTable table = null;
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    columns.add("Word");
    columns.add("Lemma");
    columns.add("monosylables");
    columns.add("Arabic");
    try{    
        File fXmlFile = new File("src/gui/TAL.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("word");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                if(nList.item(temp).getTextContent().equals(st)){
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp).getParentNode();

          if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                //System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                //System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());
                values.add(new String[]{eElement.getElementsByTagName("word").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                eElement.getElementsByTagName("lemma").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                eElement.getElementsByTagName("monosylables").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                eElement.getElementsByTagName("arabic").item(0).getTextContent()});
                                TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(values.toArray(new Object[][] {}), columns.toArray());
                                table = new JTable(tableModel);

      }
            }
        }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return table;

}
/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Frame1() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    searchField = new JTextField();
    searchField.addActionListener(new SearchActionListener());
    frame.getContentPane().add(searchField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    searchField.setColumns(10);

}

class SearchDocumentListener implements DocumentListener{

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
class SearchActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String st=searchField.getText();
        JTable table=parseData(st);
        if(table!=null){
        int selectedRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
        int selectedColumnIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
        String selectedObject = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 1);
        System.out.println(selectedObject);
        }
        //JScrollPane scrollPane;
        //scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);//
        frame.getContentPane().add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        i=i+1;
    }

}
}
```

Example of the xml file that I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dictionary>
<work>
<word>kaleb</word>
<lemma>kalbon</lemma>
<monosylables>kal,eb</monosylables>
<arabic>كلب</arabic>
</work>
<work>
<word>emchi</word>
<lemma>Amchi</lemma>
<monosylables>em,chi</monosylables>
<arabic>إمشي</arabic>
</work>
</dictionary>
```

Please if any one can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create the scroll pane in your initialize() method (like the code you have commented out).

Then when you want to update the component in the scrollpane you just use:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( table );
//frame.getContentPane().add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
//frame.revalidate();
//frame.repaint();
```

No need for revalidate(), repaint() or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

the code after modification( thanks to camickr)

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Frame1 {

private JFrame frame;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTextField searchField;
int i=0;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame1 window = new Frame1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * parse Data
 */
private JTable parseData(String st){
    JTable table = null;
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    columns.add("Word");
    columns.add("Lemma");
    columns.add("monosylables");
    columns.add("Arabic");
    try{    
        File fXmlFile = new File("src/gui/TAL.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("word");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                if(nList.item(temp).getTextContent().equals(st)){
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp).getParentNode();

          if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                //System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                //System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());
                values.add(new String[]{eElement.getElementsByTagName("word").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                eElement.getElementsByTagName("lemma").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                eElement.getElementsByTagName("monosylables").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                eElement.getElementsByTagName("arabic").item(0).getTextContent()});
                                TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(values.toArray(new Object[][] {}), columns.toArray());
                                table = new JTable(tableModel);

      }
            }
        }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return table;

}
/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Frame1() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    scrollPane=new JScrollPane();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    searchField = new JTextField();
    searchField.addActionListener(new SearchActionListener());
    frame.getContentPane().add(searchField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    searchField.setColumns(10);

}

class SearchDocumentListener implements DocumentListener{

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
class SearchActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String st=searchField.getText();
        JTable table=parseData(st);
        if(table!=null){
        int selectedRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
        int selectedColumnIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
        String selectedObject = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 1);
        System.out.println(selectedObject);
        }

        //scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);//
        //frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //frame.revalidate();
        //frame.repaint();
        i=i+1;
    }

}
}
```